# Webview not rendering css properly - Kitkat version 4.4.2

Tags: android, html, css, xamarin, webview

I am not sure what's the problem is. But after googling I thought it is the problem with webview. I have a page which is rendering properly in every device except tablet with kitkat version(even in the browser of respective device, view rendered).

I googled and tried different solutions, but unfortunately nothing worked for me.

```
mapWebView.Settings.SetLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NarrowColumns); //didn't work

mapWebView.SetLayerType(LayerType.Software, null); //didn't work
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider using Chrome Custom Tabs: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem** is that you may be using design elements that WebView can't handle.

The Default Android browser - AKA "**WebView**" -

> is based on the same code as Chrome for Android version

However,

> WebView does not have full feature parity with Chrome for Android

*in other words, it's a toned down version of Chrome for Android.*

Source: [Google](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview)

Check on [Can I Use to](http://caniuse.com/) To see whether  "WebView" suppports your element or not.

Comment: I am using bootstrap and jquery. In bootstrap's documentation they have provided support for android 5.0+. [link](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/browsers-devices/). Is this might be the cause?